# ClickOnce with a Proxy server (Corporate Firewall), significant delays in checking after .application loaded

Tags: deployment, proxy, clickonce

Sometimes, when i click on my app link, it takes about 30 seconds before the app starts loading, while it's in the verifying stage.  Other times, with the same install, one which i have loaded and used many times, it takes no time at all.  Why?  What can i change about the deployment to stop this?  Please note that i have no admin access to the proxy server, nor possibility of changing the proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a performance issue that you need to take up with the guys who support the proxy server. The request is hitting the proxy server and waiting for it to give permission to come through andretrieve the files. It probably depends on how much traffic the server has at any given time.